# How to get updated value from wicket textfield/model

Tags: wicket, wicket-6

```
final TextField<Double> regularPrice = new TextField<Double>("regular", new PropertyModel<Double>(listItem.getModel(), "price"))
 {
   private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

   @Override
   protected void onConfigure() 
   {
     super.onConfigure();                 
     setEnabled(cashflowStatus.compareTo(CashflowStatus.M_MANUAL) < 0);
   }
 };
 listItem.add(regularPrice);



regularPrice.add(new AjaxFormComponentUpdatingBehavior("onChange")
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Override
    protected void onUpdate(AjaxRequestTarget target)
    {
      Double updatedValue = listItem.getModelObject().getPrice());
    }               
});
```

I wan to get new updated value on change but I am getting the old value from the model. Isn't model get updated and it should give new updated value. Please let me know, what is getting wrong in above code and how to get updated value ?

Answer (score 0):

You should also re-render your component :)

```
 @Override
protected void onUpdate(AjaxRequestTarget target)
{
  Double updatedValue = listItem.getModelObject().getPrice());
  target.add(this.getComponent());
}
```